# ravendb query locationsbyip index

Tags: indexing, ravendb, querying

I have the following two class definitions:

```
public class Location : Doc
{
    public string Country { get; set; }
    public string Region { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string PostalCode { get; set; }
    public Double Latitude { get; set; }
    public Double Longitude { get; set; }
    public string MetroCode { get; set; }
    public string AreaCode { get; set; }
    public List<IpRange> IpRanges { get; set; }
}
```

and

```
public class IpRange
{
    public long Start { get; set; }
    public long End { get; set; }
}
```

I have an index defined as follows:

```
public class Locations_ByRange : AbstractIndexCreationTask<Location>
{
    public Locations_ByRange()
    {
        Map = locations =>
            from location in locations
            from range in location.IpRanges
            select new
            {
                range.Start,
                range.End
            };
    }
}
```

I then try to query the index as follows:

```
var queryable = DocumentSession.Query<IpRange, Locations_ByRange>()
                        .FirstOrDefault(x => x.Start <= reverseIp && x.End >= reverseIp) ?? new IpRange();
```

But, I am met with the following error when running the query:

```
Exception Details: System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'Jodolo.Data.Locations.Location' to type 'Jodolo.Data.Locations.IpRange'.
```

And, here is the StackTrace:

```
    [InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'Jodolo.Data.Locations.Location' to type 'Jodolo.Data.Locations.IpRange'.]
   Raven.Client.Document.InMemoryDocumentSessionOperations.TrackEntity(String key, RavenJObject document, RavenJObject metadata, Boolean noTracking) in c:\Builds\RavenDB-Stable\Raven.Client.Lightweight\Document\InMemoryDocumentSessionOperations.cs:357
   Raven.Client.Document.SessionOperations.QueryOperation.Deserialize(RavenJObject result) in c:\Builds\RavenDB-Stable\Raven.Client.Lightweight\Document\SessionOperations\QueryOperation.cs:167
   System.Linq.WhereSelectListIterator`2.MoveNext() +104
   System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection) +381
   System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList(IEnumerable`1 source) +58
   Raven.Client.Document.SessionOperations.QueryOperation.Complete() in c:\Builds\RavenDB-Stable\Raven.Client.Lightweight\Document\SessionOperations\QueryOperation.cs:143
   Raven.Client.Document.AbstractDocumentQuery`2.GetEnumerator() in c:\Builds\RavenDB-Stable\Raven.Client.Lightweight\Document\AbstractDocumentQuery.cs:891
   System.Linq.Enumerable.FirstOrDefault(IEnumerable`1 source) +152
   Raven.Client.Linq.RavenQueryProviderProcessor`1.GetQueryResult(IDocumentQuery`1 finalQuery) in c:\Builds\RavenDB-Stable\Raven.Client.Lightweight\Linq\RavenQueryProviderProcessor.cs:1529
   Raven.Client.Linq.RavenQueryProviderProcessor`1.ExecuteQuery() in c:\Builds\RavenDB-Stable\Raven.Client.Lightweight\Linq\RavenQueryProviderProcessor.cs:1454
   Raven.Client.Linq.RavenQueryProviderProcessor`1.Execute(Expression expression) in c:\Builds\RavenDB-Stable\Raven.Client.Lightweight\Linq\RavenQueryProviderProcessor.cs:1427
   Raven.Client.Linq.RavenQueryProvider`1.Execute(Expression expression) in c:\Builds\RavenDB-Stable\Raven.Client.Lightweight\Linq\RavenQueryProvider.cs:155
   Raven.Client.Linq.RavenQueryProvider`1.System.Linq.IQueryProvider.Execute(Expression expression) in c:\Builds\RavenDB-Stable\Raven.Client.Lightweight\Linq\RavenQueryProvider.cs:198
   System.Linq.Queryable.FirstOrDefault(IQueryable`1 source, Expression`1 predicate) +287
```

.
.
.

I am somewhat pleased to see this, because ultimately I am trying to retrieve the Location document that satisfies the query parameters. It's clear that I can change the type declaration on the query call to

```
.Query<Location, Locations_ByRange>()
```

But, I then have trouble figuring out how to query the fields stored in the index; since there are no Start and End fields defined for a Location object.

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your query to:

```
using Raven.Client;

...

var location = session.Query<IpRange, Locations_ByRange>()
                      .Where(x => x.Start <= reverseIp && x.End >= reverseIp)
                      .As<Location>()
                      .FirstOrDefault();
```

In your index, you may need to add sorting hints:

```
public class Locations_ByRange : AbstractIndexCreationTask<Location, IpRange>
{
    public Locations_ByRange()
    {
        Map = locations =>
            from location in locations
            from range in location.IpRanges
            select new
            {
                range.Start,
                range.End
            };

        Sort(x => x.Start, SortOptions.Long);
        Sort(x => x.End, SortOptions.Long);
    }
}
```

Note that I added the return type at the top in `AbstractIndexCreationTask<Location, IpRange>`.  This will align the types so the `Sort` method can locate those properties.

Comment: I can't build if I simply change the query as you specified. Is there a using statement I need to add to the class?

Comment: See my updated answer on how to modify the index to add sorting hints.  Without them, those fields are probably sorting with string ordering and throwing off the range query.

Comment: If you're on RavenDB 2.5, you might instead try using `ResultsTransformers` which are a new feature.  The api is a bit cleaner.  You can find some examples in the docs [here](http://ravendb.net/docs/2.5/client-api/querying/results-transformation/result-transformers)

Comment: I figured it out. The As<T> method is an extension method in the LinqExtensions class which resides within the Raven.Client namespace. I just changed Raven.Client.Linq to Raven.Client and everything worked great. Thanks for your help Matt.

Comment: My bad.  You are correct.  Do be careful of the sort order though. :)